# Are there any specific method get all Nfts by their GroupPointer of `findAllByUpdateAuthority` in the SPL-token 2022?

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, nft, token-2022

I'm trying to find all the nft from a same group for a newly created SPL-token-2022 nfts. Previously doing that with metaplex was easy, But now i'm using the new standards.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it with the current libraries, but you can probably code it up yourself.

The question is a bit vague, because you mention all NFTs from the same group, but then bring up their `GroupPointer` extension. The `GroupPointer` extension just points to another account that has the group info. If that points to a metaplex collection, then everything works as normal!

But if you're using the new `TokenGroup` and `TokenMember` extensions, then you'll need to search through all token-2022 mints with `getProgramAccounts` and parse their data to see if they belong to a particular group.

Many RPCs limit `getProgramAccounts` for token programs, so you may need to look for some other solution.